# Form field validation - who renders the error?

Tags: django

I have a model which contains 2 fields of type `PositiveSmallIntegerField`.
And I have a `ModelForm` for this model and these fields.

My validation works fine. But if I type in negative number or alphanumeric string, I get the validation error as some sort of pop-up(see images below). My question: is the validation error rendered by the browser? Shouldn't the error be rendered by Django as HTML code?
And can I translate this error with django translations?

Also, in my `clean` method of the form I have a custom validation and I do this:

```
if cleaned_data['capacity_min'] > cleaned_data['capacity_max']:
    raise ValidationError(_("Some message"))
```

I can translate this one and it is rendered as I was expected, simple HTML code in the page

Thank you

This is what happens with firefox

[image]

This is what happens with Google Chrome
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These hint errors are showed by browser.  Browser rejects to submit the invalid form to the server so your django validation didn't even run.

To solve this problem change the widget for you field from `NumberInput` to `TextInput`:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        ...
        widgets = {
            'capacity_min': forms.TextInput(),
            'capacity_max': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

Comment: But if the browser has precedence before Django, this means that the field errors will never get to be rendered? and this fully depends on the way the client(user) has configured his browser?

Comment: Yes, modern browsers do some validation for `<input type="number">` fields and you can't prevent this behaviour.  But you can use `type="text"` instead of `type="number"` attribute in your form.

Comment: I added example of overriding default widgets for form fields. See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: I know how to override widgets, I was just thinking how to get rid of this browser validation. Thanks